# Do Rails routes bubble up somehow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following case is accidental. It is working but I don't know why.

In my routes, I have the following:

```ruby
namespace :pro do
  resources :stores do
    resources :reports do
      resources :reviews, only: :index do
        collection do
          get :best
          get :chart
          post '/share', to: 'shared_links#create', defaults: { format: :json }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


> bin/rake routes -g shared_links
Running via Spring preloader in process 70060
                         Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                           Controller#Action
share_pro_store_reports_reviews POST /pro/stores/:store_id/reports/reviews/share(.:format) pro/reports/shared_links#create {:format=>:json}
```

So far, so good.

By mistake, the following controller was created:

```ruby
# app/controllers/pro/shared_links_controller.rb

class Pro::SharedLinksController < Pro::ApplicationController
  # POST /pro/stores/:store_id/reports/reviews/share
  def create
  end
end
```

Instead of

```ruby
# app/controllers/pro/reports/shared_links_controller.rb

class Pro::Reports::SharedLinksController < Pro::ApplicationController
  # POST /pro/stores/:store_id/reports/reviews/share
  def create
  end
end
```

Now, the strange thing happens.

In `development` environment, everything works fine despite the obvious mistake:

```ruby
Started POST "/pro/stores/hap0b/reports/reviews/share" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 15:31:07 +0200
Processing by Pro::SharedLinksController#create as JSON
```

In a non-`development` environment, the behaviour is different and actually, is as expected:

```ruby
Started POST "/pro/stores/hapba/reports/reviews/share" for 34.203.239.149 at 2017-08-25 13:00:40 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Pro::Reports::SharedLinksController)
Did you mean?  Pro::SharedLinksController
```

One last thing I could observe is that when creating `Pro::Reports::SharedLinksController#create` in `development`, it is the one that is actually called.

So this makes me wonder if there is some kind of fallback/bubble logics going on.

Comment: I guess that's a bug, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MSathieu I guess we'll see then :) : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30419

Comment: Nice idea to open a report